# Multi Class XML Serializer generates mostly blank XML file

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I am trying to create a Multi Class XML file so I can better organize options in my configuration file. Reason is that this program has several different functions I don't want all of the options smashed together in the XML.

Here is my code for the XML

```
[Serializable]
public class Database
{
    public string DatabaseAddress { get; set; }
    public int DatabasePort { get; set; }
    public string DatabaseName { get; set; }
    public string DatabaseTableName { get; set; }
    public string DatabaseUsername { get; set; }
    public string DatabasePassword { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Tools
{
    public bool EnableStaffManager { get; set; }
    public string StaffManagerChatColor { get; set; }
    public bool EnableServerSecurity { get; set; }

}

[Serializable]
public class StaffManager
{
    public bool EnableDutyAnnouncer { get; set; }
    public bool RemoveAdminOnLogout { get; set; }
    public List<Mod> Mods { get; set; }
    public List<Admin> Admins { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Loadout
{
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }

}

public class PToolsConfiguration : IRocketPluginConfiguration
{
    Database db = new Database();
    Tools t = new Tools();
    StaffManager sm = new StaffManager();
    Loadout l = new Loadout();

    public void LoadDefaults()
    {
        db.DatabaseAddress = "localhost";
        db.DatabasePort = 3306;
        db.DatabaseName = "unturned";
        db.DatabaseTableName = "PTools";
        db.DatabaseUsername = "unturned";
        db.DatabasePassword = "password";

        t.EnableStaffManager = true;
        t.StaffManagerChatColor = "red";
        t.EnableServerSecurity = true;

        sm.EnableDutyAnnouncer = true;
        sm.RemoveAdminOnLogout = true;

        l.Items = new List<Item>() {
                    new Item() {
                        Id = 203,
                        Amt = 1
                    },
                    new Item() {
                        Id = 1015,
                        Amt = 1
                    },
                    new Item() {
                        Id = 1016,
                        Amt = 1
                    },
                    new Item() {
                        Id = 1017,
                        Amt = 3
                    },
                    new Item() {
                        Id = 333,
                        Amt = 3
                    },
                    new Item() {
                        Id = 93,
                        Amt = 3
                    },
                    new Item() {
                        Id = 466,
                        Amt = 2
                    },
                    new Item() {
                        Id = 151,
                        Amt = 1
                    },
                    new Item() {
                        Id = 345,
                        Amt = 1
                    },
                    new Item() {
                        Id = 347,
                        Amt = 15
                    },
                };
        sm.Mods = new List<Mod>() {
                   new Mod() {
                       STEAM64 = "76555555555551633"
                    }
                };
        sm.Admins = new List<Admin>() {
                   new Admin() {
                       STEAM64 = "76555555555551633"
                    }
                };
    }
}
```

And here is the XML it produces...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PToolsConfiguration xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" />
```

so I am tying to figure out what I am doing wrong that it's not generating the entire XML File... Thanks!

---

Want to officially give credit to jdweng for his answer was exactly what I was looking for. Here is the output after using his code.

```
<PToolsConfiguration xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Database>
    <DatabaseAddress>localhost</DatabaseAddress>
    <DatabasePort>3306</DatabasePort>
    <DatabaseName>unturned</DatabaseName>
    <DatabaseTableName>PTools</DatabaseTableName>
    <DatabaseUserName>unturned</DatabaseUserName>
    <DatabasePassword>password</DatabasePassword>
  </Database>
  <Tools>
    <EnableStaffManager>true</EnableStaffManager>
    <StaffManagerChatColor>red</StaffManagerChatColor>
    <EnableServerSecurity>true</EnableServerSecurity>
  </Tools>
  <StaffManager>
    <EnableDutyAnnouncer>true</EnableDutyAnnouncer>
    <RemoveAdminOnLogout>true</RemoveAdminOnLogout>
    <Mods>76555555555551633</Mods>
    <Admins>76555555555551633</Admins>
  </StaffManager>
  <Loadout>
    <Items>
      <Id>203</Id>
      <Amt>1</Amt>
    </Items>
    <Items>
      <Id>1015</Id>
      <Amt>1</Amt>
    </Items>
    <Items>
      <Id>1016</Id>
      <Amt>1</Amt>
    </Items>
    <Items>
      <Id>1017</Id>
      <Amt>3</Amt>
    </Items>
    <Items>
      <Id>333</Id>
      <Amt>3</Amt>
    </Items>
    <Items>
      <Id>93</Id>
      <Amt>3</Amt>
    </Items>
    <Items>
      <Id>466</Id>
      <Amt>2</Amt>
    </Items>
    <Items>
      <Id>151</Id>
      <Amt>1</Amt>
    </Items>
    <Items>
      <Id>345</Id>
      <Amt>1</Amt>
    </Items>
    <Items>
      <Id>347</Id>
      <Amt>15</Amt>
    </Items>
  </Loadout>
</PToolsConfiguration>
```

Thanks everyone for your quick feedback.

Comment: Can you explain what `Multi Class XML` is including your code to generate it.

Comment: Where's the actual call to the serializer?

Comment: @Eser, generating an xml using the classes like I did above is supposed to be a way to better organize the final serialized output. The format of the XML will be easier to read as a result.

Comment: @GeorgeJohnston The serializer call is included in the API that I am developing for. The ": IRocketPluginConfiguration" tells  the core of the API that this is what needs serialized.

Comment: @AndrewDillon My knowledge is limited. Can you post a link explaining what a `Multi Class XML` is ?

Comment: Please keep in mind I am a self taught and still learning c# developer. I learn everything from reading, and asking here and a few select friends. 'Multi Class XML' isn't like an official term for it or anything, all I know is using more then one class to create the XML is a great way to organize your XML. Here is one of the many links I read when researching it. http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/b81385/best-practices-in-net-xml-serialization-of-complex-classes/....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        }
    }
    [XmlRoot("PToolsConfiguration")]
    public class PToolsConfiguration 
    {
        [XmlElement("Database")]
        public Database db { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("Tools")]
        public Tools t { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("StaffManager")]
        public StaffManager sm { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("Loadout")]
        public Loadout l { get; set; }

        public PToolsConfiguration()
        {
            db = new Database();
            t = new Tools();
            sm = new StaffManager();
            l = new Loadout();
        }
        public void LoadDefaults()
        {
            db.DatabaseAddress = "localhost";
            db.DatabasePort = 3306;
            db.DatabaseName = "unturned";
            db.DatabaseTableName = "PTools";
            db.DatabaseUsername = "unturned";
            db.DatabasePassword = "password";

            t.EnableStaffManager = true;
            t.StaffManagerChatColor = "red";
            t.EnableServerSecurity = true;

            sm.EnableDutyAnnouncer = true;
            sm.RemoveAdminOnLogout = true;

            l.Items = new List<Item>() {
                    new Item() {
                        Id = 203,
                        Amt = 1
                    },
                    new Item() {
                        Id = 1015,
                        Amt = 1
                    },
                    new Item() {
                        Id = 1016,
                        Amt = 1
                    },
                    new Item() {
                        Id = 1017,
                        Amt = 3
                    },
                    new Item() {
                        Id = 333,
                        Amt = 3
                    },
                    new Item() {
                        Id = 93,
                        Amt = 3
                    },
                    new Item() {
                        Id = 466,
                        Amt = 2
                    },
                    new Item() {
                        Id = 151,
                        Amt = 1
                    },
                    new Item() {
                        Id = 345,
                        Amt = 1
                    },
                    new Item() {
                        Id = 347,
                        Amt = 15
                    },
                };
            sm.Mods = new List<string>() { "76555555555551633"};

            sm.Admins = new List<string>() {"76555555555551633"};

        }
    }

    [XmlRoot("Database")]
    public class Database
    {
        [XmlElement("DatabaseAddress")]
        public string DatabaseAddress { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("DatabasePort")]
        public int DatabasePort { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("DatabaseName")]
        public string DatabaseName { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("DatabaseTableName")]
        public string DatabaseTableName { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("DatabaseUserName")]
        public string DatabaseUsername { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("DatabasePassword")]
        public string DatabasePassword { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot("Tools")]
    public class Tools
    {
        [XmlElement("EnableStaffManager")]
        public bool EnableStaffManager { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("StaffManagerChatColor")]
        public string StaffManagerChatColor { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("EnableServerSecurity")]
        public bool EnableServerSecurity { get; set; }

    }

    [XmlRoot("StaffManager")]
    public class StaffManager
    {
        [XmlElement("EnableDutyAnnouncer")]
        public bool EnableDutyAnnouncer { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("RemoveAdminOnLogout")]
        public bool RemoveAdminOnLogout { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("Mods")]
        public List<string> Mods { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("Admins")]
        public List<string> Admins { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot("Loadout")]
    public class Loadout
    {
        [XmlElement("Items")]
        public List<Item> Items { get; set; }

    }
    [XmlRoot("Item")]
    public class Item
    {
        [XmlElement("Id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("Amt")]
        public Single Amt { get; set; }

    }


}
​
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to type this up, going to test it now.

Comment: Thank you, after one minor type edit, this worked perfectly! Life saver!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are serializing an instance of the `PToolsConfiguration` class which doesn't have any public properties. As a result, that is precisely what the resultant XML should look like.